# Render a user control ascx

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I want to use an ascx as a template, and render it programatically, using the resulting html as the return value of an ajax method.

```
Page pageHolder = new Page();
MyUserControl ctlRender = (MyUserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(typeof(MyUserControl),null);

pageHolder.Controls.Add(ctlRender);
System.IO.StringWriter swOutput = new System.IO.StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, swOutput, false);
return swOutput.ToString();
```

This all executes, and the Page Load event of the user control fires, but the StringWriter is always empty.  I've seen similar code to this in other examples, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I also get empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
public string RenderControl(Control ctrl) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Taken directly from the article here:

[ASP.NET Tip: Render Control into HTML String](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/859.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You always have to use something like this.Controls.Add(TemplateControl.LoadControl("~/PathTo/YourControl.ascx")

The reason is, that there is no internal mapping of Types to there ascx-file (only the other way arround). So this means if you initialize new YourControl(), it will not do anything you defined in the ascx part. If you would have

```
protected override void protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output) {
    output.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

this would give you "Test" in the place you rendered your control to.